# Matrix optimization with inverse of symmetric positive definite (SPD)

Tags: positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

I'm considering the following optimization problem:

$$\min_{\mathbf{A}\succ \mathbf{0}}  \frac{\mbox{tr} \left(\mathbf{S}\mathbf{A}\right)}{\mbox{tr}\left(\mathbf{D}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\right)}$$

where matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ is symmetric and positive definite (SPD), matrix $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ is the inverse of $\mathbf{A}$. Both $\mathbf{S} \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ and $\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ are SPD matrices. Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  At first glance it seems you can make the ratio arbitrarily small by taking $A$ to be a small positive multiple of the identity, so the numerator becomes small while the denominator grows large.

Comment: Sharing the context of your problem would help make it better.  A special case might need to be considered where $\operatorname{tr} D$ is zero, but since you require $D$ to be symmetric positive-definite, this cannot arise.  Note that for $A$ a multiple of the identity matrix the computation of traces becomes easy, almost to the point of triviality.